# Wrap text of Listboxitem

Tags: c#, wpf

i have written this code and i would like to be able to resize the window so that the text of the listboxitems wrap according to that. Atm, idk why, some text is already wider then the listbox itself and pushes itself and the expander out of the listbox.

If anybody knows an overall better solution then using a listbox, that would be great. I just would like to be able to have a list with items i can easily update and have a checkbox for all of them and a small explanation text for them, but a listbox is the best i came up with.

Edited Code for clearance

```
            <TabItem x:Name="TabItem02" Header="">
                <ListBox x:Name="listBox01" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <CheckBox Margin="5,2" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item01" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item02" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item03" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item04" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item05" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item06" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item07" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item08" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item09" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item10" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item11" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item12" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item13" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item14" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item15" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item16" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item17" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item18" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item19" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item20" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item21" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item22" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item23" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item24" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item25" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item26" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item27" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item28" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item29" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item30" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item31" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item32" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item33" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item34" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item35" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item36" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item37" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item38" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item39" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="List1Item40" IsEnabled="False"/>
                </ListBox>
            </TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your Expander and TextBlock are in grid column 1, which has * width. For the control to be able to wrap text it needs to be limited in width. Try setting a smaller fixed width for column 1 and it should wrap. Then solve the element arrangement as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i changed it according to your suggestion, but the main problem is still there. The Text of the listboxitems themself, which i add in my code-behind through langauge files, is sometimes to large and pushes itself and the expander out of the listbox. This is the text i meant that does not wrap, not the textbox itself, sry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after a lot of try and error i managed to get it working by myself. What i have done is to create a contenttemplate for the contentpresenter and have a textblock in it binding to the content of the contentpresenter which is the listboxitem.

```
<TabItem Name="TabItem02" Header="">
            <ListBox Name="listBox01" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedValuePath="Content">
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <CheckBox Margin="5,2" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                            </ContentPresenter>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                        <Expander Header="Explanation" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item01" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item02" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item03" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item04" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <ListBoxItem Name="List1Item05" IsEnabled="False"/>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>
```